# Core Data fetch using predicate with date calculation sometimes crashing

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a `ResponseCacheRecord` entity in my Core Data model with these attributes (amongst a few others):

- `removeWhenExpired` (non-optional Boolean)
- `timestamp` (non-optional Date)
- `validDuration` (non-optional Double)

The managed object looks like this:

```
extension ResponseCacheRecord {
    @NSManaged var identifier: String
    @NSManaged var timestamp: Date
    @NSManaged var validDuration: TimeInterval
    @NSManaged var removeWhenExpired: Bool
    // ...
}

class ResponseCacheRecord: NSManagedObject {

    @objc var expired: Bool {
        let age =  Date().timeIntervalSince(timestamp)
        return age > validDuration
    }

    override func awakeFromInsert() {
        super.awakeFromInsert()
        timestamp = Date()
    }
}
```

I have written a fetch request to return all the expired `ResponseCacheRecord`s that should be removed based on the following condition:

```
(removeWhenExpired == true) && (timestamp < Date() - validDuration)
```

The fetch looks like this:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<ResponseCacheRecord>(entityName: "ResponseCacheRecord")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(removeWhenExpired == YES) AND (timestamp < (CAST(%@, 'NSNumber') - validDuration))", NSDate())    
do {
    let expiredRecords = try `default`.managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
} catch {
    // Error handling...
}
```

But we are getting some crash reports in that point to an issue during the call to `fetch(_:)`:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[__NSCFNumber timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cc0287e0

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18489ad8c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x183a545ec objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1848a8098 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1848a05c8 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18478641c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1847ac580 -[NSDate compare:]
6  Foundation                     0x18534ca2c -[NSComparisonPredicateOperator performPrimitiveOperationUsingObject:andObject:]
7  Foundation                     0x1851f7548 -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:]
8  Foundation                     0x1851ff118 -[NSCompoundPredicateOperator evaluatePredicates:withObject:substitutionVariables:]
9  Foundation                     0x1851fee68 -[NSCompoundPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:]
10 CoreData                       0x18717f4ec -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]
11 CoreData                       0x1872493e0 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:]
12 CoreData                       0x187249bbc __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke
13 CoreData                       0x18724be10 internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18418ca60 _dispatch_client_callout
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1841c9ed4 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete
16 CoreData                       0x1872383b4 _perform
17 CoreData                       0x1872498b0 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]
18 CoreData                       0x18717ec30 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]
19 libswiftCoreData.dylib         0x1037dae68 NSManagedObjectContext.fetch<A where ...> (NSFetchRequest<A>) throws -> [A] (__hidden#48_:18)
20 <redacted>                     0x103293c4c specialized static ResponseCache.evictExpiredRecordsIfNecessary() -> () (ResponseCache.swift:228)
```

---

So it seems there's a problem with the predicate, and an `NSDate` selector is being called on what is actually an `NSNumber` instance. What is wrong with the predicate, how come the issue is sporadic, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect the sporadic behaviour occurs if there changes in the context (new `ResponseCacheRecord` objects, or those with changes to the relevant attributes) that have not been saved to the store.  The predicate will be converted to a SQL WHERE clause for the fetch, which works OK, but when CD has to evaluate in memory changes, it evaluates the predicate directly, which causes the exception.  `timestamp` is a `Date`, whereas `(CAST(%@, 'NSNumber') - validDuration))` is numeric, so I would focus on that.  Maybe test by evaluating the predicate in memory.

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks, that's a really helpful insight, I'll look into it.